# how to make a search functionality like the yahoo news site search

Tags: php, mysql

how to create a search functionality like the the one in this page :

http://news.maktoob.com/search?q=%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1&type=site

it searchs the database for the exact occurrence for the search text

and display the part of the content that contains this search text

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I implement a simple site search with php and mySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386914/how-would-i-implement-a-simple-site-search-with-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a search framework like lucene to perform the search and the term highlighting in the found documents for you.

This article should get you started: http://ganeshhs.com/zend-framework/zend-search-lucene-part4-search-results-highlighting