# Simple search for little website

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have website with about 100 articles which are stored in MySQL database. All connections with database are established using PDO.
Articles are average 8kB size (min is 2kB, max is 12kB). Articles count is growing about 2 every week.

My server configuration is: PHP 5.1.6, MySQL5.0.27, MySQL Engine: InnoDB. Unfortunately I do not have any influence on changing any server parameters.

I would like to add a simple search form to my site. User can type, for instance, 3 to 40 characters and articles content should be searched.  I definitely should not use `LIKE`, which is obviously easiest to code for beginner like me. I have read something about full-text search, but I am afraid that I will not be able to use it on my server.

What would you recommend me to implement simple searcher for my site? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Normally we like to see people try first, but your question is otherwise so well-asked, I'll suggest Zend Search Lucene. Have a read of [this](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/zend-search-lucene). But, if you could get into the habit of doing prior research before asking questions, it really does help show you're serious about learning `:)`.

Comment: (I don't know what Zend components generally require in terms of a PHP version, but PHP 5.1 really is ancient. Is there no way you can move to 5.2.x or 5.3? Hosting is just _so_ cheap these days.)

Comment: If you can create a database table using the MySQL engine, you could use fulltext search.  I think default shortest word for that is 4 characters though.

Comment: Full text search is only available with MyISAM tables before MySQL 5.5 or 5.6. Maybe you could convert the table containing the articles to MyISAM.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386914/how-would-i-implement-a-simple-site-search-with-php-and-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write something, I think you should dig into Full Text Search. As @Dr.biziclop noticed - you'd like to convert your DB engine to MyISAM first.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html