# Mysql search query problems

Tags: mysql, search

I am implementing a simple search in mysql as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386914/how-would-i-implement-a-simple-site-search-with-php-and-mysql) post.

My code is very similar to the example given:

```
SELECT
SUM(((LENGTH(p.body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.body, 'term', '')))/4) +
    ((LENGTH(p.body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.body, 'search', '')))/6))
AS Occurrences
FROM
    posts AS p
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    Occurrences DESC
```

which works well. The issue is I only want to select rows where the number of occurrences is greater then 0, (i.e. the rows which show any relevance to the search).

I've tried adding

```
WHERE Occurrences>0
```

making the entire code block:

```
SELECT
SUM(((LENGTH(p.body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.body, 'term', '')))/4) +
    ((LENGTH(p.body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.body, 'search', '')))/6))
AS Occurrences
FROM
    posts AS p
WHERE Occurrences>0
GROUP BY
    p.id
ORDER BY
    Occurrences DESC
```

but this always results in a query error. I've tried other WHERE clauses for testing and I've found I only get errors when trying to use the Occurrences variable.

The error is, as you might expect:

```
Unknown column 'Occurrences' in 'where clause'
```

Is there no way to do what I'm trying to do? I would rather not have to select all rows then crop out the ones I don't want in php, which seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT Occurrences FROM (
    SELECT
    SUM(((LENGTH(p.body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.body, 'term', '')))/4) +
        ((LENGTH(p.body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.body, 'search', '')))/6))
    AS Occurrences
    FROM
        posts AS p
    GROUP BY
        p.id
) AS IQ
WHERE Occurrences > 0
ORDER BY
    Occurrences DESC
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an Alias in a `WHERE` clause, only in `ODER BY` and for some SQL dialects also in `HAVING`, so you could try using `HAVING`

```
SELECT
SUM(((LENGTH(p.body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.body, 'term', '')))/4) +
    ((LENGTH(p.body) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.body, 'search', '')))/6))
AS Occurrences
FROM
    posts AS p
GROUP BY
    p.id
HAVING Occurrences>0
ORDER BY
    Occurrences DESC
```

Some reference to the problem [in the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)